# Safari and jQuery

Tags: jquery, safari

jQuery works fine in all browsers, except in Safari (both Mac and PC latest versions).
In Safary, the jQuery code is displayed as if it was html text, albeit not formatted.
I tried using jQuery instead of $, but no success.

See http://test.besaltnlight.ca for an example (use Safari to see the jQuery code).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag is incorrectly written as a self-closing tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
```

Safari correctly interprets that is an empty self-closed tag, so all of the text after it is treated as normal text, not Javascript code.

Comment: To clarify, you need to use `<script></script>` instead, even though there's no inner text

Comment: @Jeff: There is inner text; that's the point.  See his source.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I know.  I meant to say 'even if' there is no inner text, you should still use `<script></script>`.  Though I didn't notice the XHTML doctype, so perhaps it's not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Jeff: For IE, I believe it is.  However, he is closing them.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Just removing the slash fixed it!

Comment: @Slaks: that was not obvious... :(

Comment: @Gerry: Then maybe it should become more obvious.  If you have any ideas, can you please suggest them on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?